# How To Include a google apps script in a html page,that has uploading functionality on google Drive

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I just want to collect a files from users (like resume) & store on my google drive. That is working file from google apps script like below.I want to add this form to my html page. Which is provided by google as form URL

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx8w-Um_pIWx8A1S_3R2CrSYhQqyLF6tyYJOQuUHdFT5jqBFP0/exec

want to add in [shouttoday.com](http://shouttoday.com) site's page.
i also tried include as js script,or iframe but not working.

There is to files as ---

server.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Student Files";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

form.html

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Resume" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>

<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

having url app script url: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx8w-Um_pIWx8A1S_3R2CrSYhQqyLF6tyYJOQuUHdFT5jqBFP0/exec

But Don't know how to embedded this app (form) in my html page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use google developer console for this. It have programming example available for the same. So, that will really help you.